# Selenium data scraping from an interactive map

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I've seen that Selenium library for python can automate actions in a web browser and I'm trying to scrape data from this datawrapper [map](https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/arOoa/4/) that shows religious afiliation by county.
(Doing it manually would mean that I'll have to get the data of 3.2k counties for at least 5 religions)

I can see that there is a part on the HTML code that identifies each county with the 'd=...' variable and changes whenever I hover the mouse over any county in the map.

```
<path class="region-outline hover-outline has-data" d="M647.1562240889721,135.96114152215688L650.7091344625344,132.36883293125697L655.7641694711137,132.52362821915779L657.6989352777703,131.5048627657306L657.6658420742801,132.40115776793346L659.3639551774752,140.88716994963005L654.099010702,142.11879447623298L650.8229534262343,140.06256950711312L651.852692921635,137.45902563969992Z" style="vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; stroke-width: 0.9px; stroke-linejoin: round; fill: none;"></path>
```

I'm thinking about using the mouse hovering command "move_by_offset" to move the mouse over the entire map and collect the data every time that 'd' value changes.

I'm using google colab and I can't see if the code works properly.(The tutorials I've seen use javascript and shows a new browser tab where the cursor performs any instruction)

Also I can't access to "region-outline hover-outline has-data" path class nor the 'd' variable

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
def driversetup():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #run Selenium in headless mode
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    #overcome limited resource problems
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("lang=en")
    #open Browser in maximized mode
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    #disable infobars
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    #disable extension
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined});")

    return driver
driver = driversetup()
driver.get("https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/arOoa/4/")
gmap = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='us-counties-2018']/*[local-name()='g']")
```